# Shallow render doesnt render component wrapped in Consumer(jest/Enzyme)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have such a component:

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Topic from './components/Topics';
import AutoItem from './AutoItem';
import DataContext from "./dataContext";

const cx = classNames.bind(Styles);

export class TestComponent extends React.Component {


  render() {


    return (
      <div>
              <DataContext.Consumer>
                {value => (
                  <AutoItem
                    data={value}
                  />
                )}
              </DataContext.Consumer>


            <DataContext.Consumer>
              {value => (
                <Topic data={value} />
              )}
            </DataContext.Consumer>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  ...
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TestComponent);
```

I want to test it using jest/enzyme. I wrote such tests in order to check in Topic and AutoItem components render inside TestComponent:

```
describe('<TestComponent  /> Component render', () => {

  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent {...props} />);
  });

  describe('<TestComponent  /> rendering', () => {

    test('should render child components in <TestComponent  /> component', () => {
      console.log(wrapper.debug())
      expect(wrapper.find(AutoItem).length).toEqual(1);
      expect(wrapper.find(Topic).length).toEqual(1);
    });

  });
});
```

but test fails, this is what I have in console:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: 0
```

and this is output of console.log(wrapper.debug()):

```
<div className="">

            <ContextConsumer>
              [function]
            </ContextConsumer>
          </div>

          <ContextConsumer>
            [function]
          </ContextConsumer>


    </div>
```

I cannot understand why component, wrapped in Consumer doesnt render and showed as [function] in the console output. Can somebody help me with this?

```
"jest": "^24.8.0",
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
```

Based on answer I wrote this:

```
import DataContext from './dataContext';


test('should render child components in <TestComponent  /> component', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent {...props} />)
        .find(DataConsumer.Consumer)
        .renderProp('children')();

          expect(wrapper.find(AutoItem).length).toEqual(1);
          expect(wrapper.find(Topic).length).toEqual(1);
    });
```

and this is what I have in cosnole:

```
Expected: 1
Received: 0
```

and this is what I get in console when I debug wrapper:

Comment: shouldn't AutoItem in this: expect(wrapper.find(AutoItem).length).toEqual(1), be in inverted comms ('AutoItem')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Enzyme you should explicitly render `renderProp`: [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/renderProp.md)

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand what to do

Comment: I attached code above base on renderProp, it doesn't work

Comment: @rick1 renderProp name is `children` for `Consumer` not `value`